# Removing outliers from a box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I tried removing outliers from my ggplot2 boxplot, but it's not seeming to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
box_plot_osmo <- ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircAlive", y = BeforeOsmolality)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "blue")) +
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "red")) + 
  geom_hline(mapping = aes(yintercept = 780, color = "green")) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerAlive", y = DateRemovedOsmolality, color = "pink")) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

box_plot_osmo + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

Comment: You should create a more reproducible example. In this case, it would be helpful if you could share your data with `dput(recircdf)` and `dput(freezerdf)`. Based on what you've shown, I would recommend reading up on how ggplot works with "long data".

Comment: You add your boxplots via four `geom_boxplot`s. Hence, to remove the outliers you have to add `outlier.shape=NA` to each one. Adding a fifth `geom_boxplot` will have no effect on the other ones.

Comment: A conceptual sidenote: is there a sound justification to hide the existence of outliers from the audience (or yourself farther down the statistical road)? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should mention `outlier.shape=NA` in every `geom_boxplot` command to remove the outliers. I will show this with a reproducible sample data I created myself. You can use the following code:

First without removing the outliers:

```
library(tidyverse)
recircdf <- data.frame(RecircAlive = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                       RecircDead = c("B" , "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       BeforeOsmolality = c(0,100,200,300,200,300,700),
                       AfterDeathOsmolality = c(0,100,100,300,200,400,750))

freezerdf <- data.frame(FreezerAlive = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                        FreezerDead = c("B" , "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                        DateRemovedOsmolality = c(0,100,200,300,200,300,800),
                        AfterDeathOsmolality = c(0,1,200,300,400,600,800))

box_plot_osmo <- ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircAlive", y = BeforeOsmolality)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "blue")) +
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "red")) + 
  geom_hline(mapping = aes(yintercept = 780, color = "green")) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerAlive", y = DateRemovedOsmolality, color = "pink")) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

box_plot_osmo
```

Output:

[image]

Next with `outlier.shape=NA`:

```
box_plot_osmo <- ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircAlive", y = BeforeOsmolality), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(data = recircdf, mapping = aes(x = "RecircDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "blue"), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerDead", y = AfterDeathOsmolality, color = "red"), outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_hline(mapping = aes(yintercept = 780, color = "green")) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = freezerdf, mapping = aes(x = "FreezerAlive", y = DateRemovedOsmolality, color = "pink"), outlier.shape = NA) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

box_plot_osmo
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the outliers are now removed.